# How to pass recordId to model constructor from partial view rendered from a button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that renders a list of records. One of the columns is an ID (SynchronizationID). Another item is a button with a dynamically generated ID that includes "btnUpdate" concatenated with the ID column. It works perfectly.

Here is the portion of the view that renders the list as a grid:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PendingSynchronizations)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.SynchronizationID
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.CustomerName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ProductName
        </td>
        <td>
            @String.Format("{0:g}", item.LastProcessedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.OLAPServer
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.OLAPDatabase
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="@String.Format("btnUpdate{0}",item.SynchronizationID.ToString())" type="submit" value="@String.Format("{0}", (item.ApprovedFlag) ? "Reject" : "Approve")" synchId="@item.SynchronizationID.ToString()"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.ApprovedSynchDate
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have a JQuery selector that binds the buttons to my click event which works perfectly. The click event as well as the button events that handle the Accept and Cancel buttons are as follows:

```
function promptForSynchDate() {
    $('#approve-synch').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 450,
        title: 'Approve Production Synchronization ',
        buttons:
        [
            { text: "Approve", click: approveSynch },
            { text: "Cancel", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
        ]
    });
}


function approveSynch() {
    $('#approveSynchForm').submit();
}

function updateComplete() {
    alert('Production Synch Approved');
    window.location.reload();
}
```

The modal renders a partial view that contains one required field, a date, which also works perfectly. But when I enter the date and click the Accept button, the controller passes the model back to the constructor with the date field populated (which it does by calling the SET() method on that date field of the controller. But the id field I need for update is always 0.

Here is the partial view:

```
@model CubeBuilder.Site.Models.ProductionSynchDateModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ToggleApprove", "Synchronization", new { id = Model.SynchronizationId }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SynchronizationId);
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SynchronizationId);
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SyncDate);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SyncDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })        
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I don't actually need the SynchronizationId in this form. It is only there for debug purposes. I just need the date. But when the constructor is called I also need the synchronizationId so that I can update this record in the database.

Following is the Ajax call for the partial view:

```
<div id="approve-synch">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ToggleApprove", "Synchronization", new AjaxOptions() { 
    OnFailure = "updateSynchFailed", 
    OnSuccess = "updateComplete", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "approve-synch-form" }, 
    new { id = "approveSynchForm" }))
{
<div id="approve-synch-form">
@Html.Partial("ApproveSynch", new CubeBuilder.Site.Models.ProductionSynchDateModel())
</div>
}
</div>
```

I have tried everything I can think of, and will readily admit that it could just be that I am fairly new to MVC that is holding me up.

Any help would be grealy appreciated.

UPDATE:

As I continued to debug this, I added a hidden field on the view with the list of records called CurrentSynchId which I set in my button click event as follows:

`$('#CurrentSynchId').val($(this).attr('synchId'));`

Then if I add the following line to my partial view, which I definitely do not want:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SynchronizationId);
```

And finally set the value of the property in the model on my submit button handler for the submit button in the modal it works:

```
    $('#SynchronizationId').val($('#CurrentSynchId').val());
```

Here is the Model for the partial view in case that helps:

```
public class ProductionSynchDateModel
{
    public short SynchronizationId { get; set; }
    public Synchronization synchInstance { get; set; }
    private SynchronizationManager synchManager { get; set; } 

    public bool Approved
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Production Sync Date")]
    public DateTime? Schedule
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Production Sync Date")]
    public string SyncDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (Schedule.HasValue)
                return Schedule.Value.ToShortDateString();

            return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            Schedule = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        }
    }

    public ProductionSynchDateModel()
    {
    }

    public ProductionSynchDateModel(short id)
    {
        var db = EntityContext.New;
        SynchronizationId = id;

        synchManager = new SynchronizationManager(db);
        synchInstance = synchManager[SynchronizationId];
    }
}
```

Again, any help would be great. I feel like I just stumbled across something that sort of works here and I do not know why. If I remove that EditorFor() helper call from the partal view, it does not work.

UPDATED AGAIN: Nevermind. I figured it out and I understand why. I changed the EditorFor() helper to HiddenFor(), which causes the field to be pushed from the view to the partial view and saved persisted in the model for the partial view. All is fine.

I hope someone else having the same problem can gain some insite from this. It is basically a way to do grid with buttons and modals and works well.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SynchronizationId)